# iOS - How to get system log and user steps from user's device for debugging?

Tags: ios, debugging

everyone. I am trying to create a bug report page for my ios app which could send logs and user steps to my email.
For example, it could be looked like this(screenshot of Hangouts Feedback):
[Hangouts Feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FQ60.png)

In the picture, it shows you can choose to send your system data to google or not.

And I also checked out Instabug. It gathers the user steps for developer:
[Instabug User Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R001X.png)

The problem is I don't know how to get these logs. Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the general information you could do this

```
    let nsObject: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]
    let version = nsObject as! String

    let model =  UIDevice.currentDevice().model //iPhone
    let localizedModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().localizedModel //iPhone 5
    let name = UIDevice.currentDevice().name // MyIphoneName
    let osVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion //iOS 9
    let time = NSDate() //2016-05-18 20:56:48

    let batteryLevel = (100 - UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryLevel) //89%


    print("AppVersion: \(version), Model: \(model), \(localizedModel), \(name), osVersion: \(osVersion), time: \(time), batteryLevel: \(batteryLevel)%")
```

Error code would be a error you store when something fails

```
do{
let something = try getValueFromFunction()
}catch let error as NSError{
let saveThisError = error
}
```

Let me know if you need more information

Edit:

I'm not sure about the system log, but I think that is something the developer(you) need to log. There is a built in system that can store these logs, but you'll need to create the logs yourself. Read more about it here: [Logging Errors and Warnings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/LoggingErrorsAndWarnings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW8-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. How about user steps? I know How to get the console log but you cannot put NSLog everywhere. Seems like I should take a look at app's system log. How to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you can read more about it in the link I provided in my answer. Please upvote if my answer was helpful or mark it as answered!